# Symfony & React Axios not work on Apache Server

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony, axios, symfony6

I used my Symfony server on localhost to test and develop my website, but I need to test something with friends so I uploaded that website to the Apache server, also I am using React as frontend, so I have an API controller where I am trying to send Axios POST request, now to the problem.

Axios Requests works and API updates everything in Database, but I think Axios can't receive any response from API even UseState not works, every modal that I have works fine as well.

APIConroller

```
#[Route('/trades/deleteScreenshot/{id}', name: 'app_api_delete_screenshot', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function deleteScreenshot(Trade $trade, Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        /**
         * @var User $user
         */
        $user = $this->getUser();

        // Checking if the user has access to the trading account
        if ($trade->getAccount()->getTrader() !== $user) {
            return $this->apiResponse([
                'errors' => [
                    'You do not have access to this trade.'
                ]
            ], Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
        }

        $tempScreenshots = $trade->getScreenshots();

        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        unset($tempScreenshots[$data['screenshot']]);

        $trade->setScreenshots($tempScreenshots);
        $this->entityManager->persist($trade);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        return $this->apiResponse([
            'message' => 'Screenshot has been deleted.',
            'trade' => $this->serializer->serialize($trade, 'json', [
                AbstractNormalizer::GROUPS => ['public']
            ]),
            'account' => $this->serializer->serialize($trade->getAccount(), 'json', [
                AbstractNormalizer::GROUPS => ['public']
            ]),
            'user' => $this->serializer->serialize($user, 'json', [
                AbstractNormalizer::GROUPS => ['public']
            ]),
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Axios Request Method

```
const handleDeleteScreenshot = (trade) => {
        if (trade !== null) {
            setLoading(true)

            axios.post(Links.deleteScreenshot(trade), data)
                .then(response => {
                    const responseData = response.data.data;

                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        toast.success(responseData.message)
                        updateTrade(JSON.parse(responseData.trade)) //UseState update
                        onClose()
                    }

                    setLoading(false) //Loading icon in button
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    const responseData = error.response.data.data;

                    if (responseData.errors) {
                        responseData.errors.map(error => toast.error(error))
                        setErrors(responseData.errors)
                    } else {
                        toast.error('Unknown error occurred, please try again later.')
                    }

                    setLoading(false) //Loading icon in button
                })
        }
    }
```

The problem what I am experiencing is on localhost everything works fine, but on Apache Server (VPS) not working.

Btw. In profiler toolbar it show AJAX request, but when I click on it it shows this
`Token "1e0b27" not found.`

And I am using Symfony UX Turbo.

I have tried to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin and still not works.

Comment: What does your network tab in developers console say?  Is the payload there?  What is the response?

Comment: Sorry, I have it in Czech language, but on the right side is the response and the last line appears when clicking on request: https://imgtr.ee/i/T1V13

Comment: Well the response is there .. So AXIOS is getting that same response .. I'd compare, and check the responses between your locahost and apache server.

Comment: Ye just tried and seems on localhost it returns only JSON and on Production returning JSON response and profiler as on Image, just disabled the profiler in API and delete works, will try other API requests. BUT Thanks for the help, seems finally its fixed